# Local Static variable initialization is thread safe

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Suppose I have  a class with three  static functions like this :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <thread>


class Employee
{

};

class client
{

public:
    void Doprocessing()
    {
        //is this thread safe in c++11/14
        static int i = CreateEmployee();

        //does it look good to use static variable like this to make it thread safe?
        static int k = ProcessEmploye();
    }

private:


    static int CreateEmployee()
    {
        static Employee * e = new Employee();
        InsertEmployee(e);
        return 1;
    }

    static int  InsertEmployee(Employee *e)
    {
        vec.push_back(e);
        return 1;
    }

    static int ProcessEmploye()
    {
        Employee* e = vec[0];
        //do something with e
        //...
        //.
        //Suppose 10 -20 lines 
        return 1;
    }


    static std::vector<Employee*> vec;
};

std::vector<Employee*> client::vec;

void func()
{
    client cobj;
    cobj.Doprocessing();
}

const int No_Of_Threads = 10;
int main() {


    std::thread * threadpointer = new std::thread[No_Of_Threads];

    std::srand(11);
    for (int i = 0; i < No_Of_Threads; i++)
    {
        threadpointer[i] = std::thread(func);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < No_Of_Threads; i++)
    {
        threadpointer[i].join();
    }
    delete[] threadpointer;

    std::cout << " Good" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are :
1)If I use static int i = Somefunc() and no matter how bulky somefunc is,  will be called **once** and  will it be **thread safe** ?
2) if answer of 1) is yes, Does it look good to programers eyes to use static int i = SomeFunc() for above purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will be thread safe, but only since C++11. Static variables are initialized in thread safe way, they are often also called magic statics.

For more see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables

> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with std::call_once).
>   Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean comparison.

Also - in your code you call CreateEmployee(); during initialization of `static i`, and `CreateEmployee(` also initializes a static variable. This should also be OK, you can find in standard following footnote:

> The implementation must not introduce any deadlock around execution of the 
>   initializer.

As to your second question, from the code you have shown I dont see that it is OK to use static variable as a way to gain thread safety.

Are you aware that specifying a variable as static inside function body allows you to assign it only once? This means your CreateEmployee() will always return the same Employee instance.

Comment: Yes I am aware that static initialized only once since old standards.