# Singleton constructor with local static variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, singleton

I'm doing an exercise with Singleton design pattern. From the discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487075/local-static-variable-initialization-is-thread-safe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11), I understand the initialization of local static variable is thread safe since C++11. Please consider the code snippet below,

```
std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade> ApiFacade::GetInstance(const std::string & url)
{
    // Initialization of function-local statics is guaranteed to occur only
    // once even when called from multiple threads, and may be more efficient
    // than the equivalent code using std::call_once.
    static std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade> rest = nullptr;
    if (rest == nullptr)
    {
        if (!url.empty())
        {
            rest = std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade>(new ApiFacade(url));
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Failed creating REST API object, Pass a valid URL");
        }
    }

    return rest;
}
```

Here the local static is initialized with `nullptr` first and then assigned with the appropriate pointer using `rest = std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade>(new ApiFacade(url));`. I want to know whether the thread safe is ensured until the local `static` is assigned with an instance of `ApiFacade` or should I still need to use the [DCLP](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) for this case. Here the local `static` initialization is done with `nullptr` and later with an instance of `ApiFacade`.

However I tried to address the race condition as below but @Etherealone solution looks good

```
{
    static std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade> rest = nullptr;

    if (rest == nullptr)
    {
        // Mutex to provide exclusive access to resource.
        std::recursive_mutex singleTonMtx = {};
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(singleTonMtx);
        if (!url.empty() && (rest == nullptr))
        {
            rest = std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade>(new ApiFacade(url));
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Failed creating API object, Pass a valid URL");
        }
    }

    return rest;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `static std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade> rest = std::make_shared<ApiFacade>(url); return rest;`. Your version is not thread_safe.

Comment: @Jarod42, I understand that but I need to validate `url` prior creating `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: whereas `Singleton` is generally an anti-pattern, singleton with non default constructor is worse (as it depends of previous call)...

Comment: @Jarod42, Yes, I understand that. The `std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade> ApiFacade::GetInstance(const std::string & url)` has default parameter. So you could just invoke `ApiFacade::GetInstance()`.

Comment: I mean that your are not sure which url is used when you do `ApiFacade::GetInstance(myUrl);` (or `ApiFacade::GetInstance();`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not thread-safe. Thread-safety ends with the initialization of variable `rest` with `nullptr`. Multiple threads can run the code following that in parallel.

The thread-safe version would be this:

```
std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade> ApiFacade::GetInstance(const std::string & url) {
    // Initialization of function-local statics is guaranteed to occur only
    // once even when called from multiple threads, and may be more efficient
    // than the equivalent code using std::call_once.
    static std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade> rest = nullptr;

    if (rest == nullptr)
    {
        if (!url.empty())
        {
            std::shared_ptr<ApiFacade> empty_rest;
            std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&rest, &empty_rest, std::make_shared<ApiFacade>(url));
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Failed creating REST API object, Pass a valid URL");
        }
    }

    return rest;
}
```

But this only updates the `rest` if it is empty. I am not sure if that is the desired behaviour.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that, as @Jarod42 says, more than one `ApiFacade` class may get constructed. Only one will get to stay and the others will be destructed as a result of failing comparison to `empty_rest`.

Also, I should point out for the others that there is still some kind of logical race-y situation here. When the function is being called by multiple threads for the first time, if different `url` parameters are used by different threads, a random `url` will be successfully used while constructing the `rest` and others will be discarded. However, other than that, there is no undefined behavior so the code block is safe to use.

Comment: Not that several `ApiFacade` can be construct here.